# set timeout across domain for Test-NetConnection or 5985 in Powershell

Tags: multithreading, powershell, parallel-processing, runspace

I've got this running but I changed the `PortOpen` because if systems were down, this block would take too long to run. However, after I made the change, I thought I was good until I had come to test it again and again and somehow, I have different results for systems. Sometimes the same system comes up twice without the other. And sometimes doubles of both. I had hoped I can set the timeout faster this way. The `PortOpen` line does work, but I'm not sure how to get it to work as a whole within this job. Basically, I'm not sure how to structure this to be able to leverage that piece.

```
    $ProgressPreference = 'Ignore'
    $maxThreads = 32

    $pool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $maxThreads,
                        [initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault2(), 
$Host)

    $pool.Open()

    $jobs = [System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]]::new()
    $servers = ( Get-ADComputer -filter * -searchbase "OU=Sales, DC=example,DC=com" | Select-Object -expand Name )
    $servers | ForEach-Object {
        $instance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
            param($computer)
    
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Computer = $computer
                Port     = 5985
                #PortOpen =  Test-NetConnection $computer -Port 5985 -InformationLevel Quiet
                PortOpen =  [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]::new().ConnectAsync($computer, 5985).Wait(100) 
            }
        }).AddParameters(@{ computer = $_ })
    
        $instance.RunspacePool = $pool
        
        $jobs.Add(@{
            Instance = $instance
            Async    = $instance.BeginInvoke()
        })
    }
    
    $result = while($jobs) {
        $job = $jobs[[System.Threading.WaitHandle]::WaitAny($jobs.Async.AsyncWaitHandle)]
        $job.Instance.EndInvoke($job.Async)
        $job.Instance.Dispose()
        $null = $jobs.Remove($job)
    }
    
    $pool.Dispose()
    
    $online = @()
    $online += $result | Where-Object PortOpen | ForEach-Object Computer
    Write-Output $online
```

Comment: your code looks fine. 100 milliseconds for the waiting is really too little time. please add how `$pool` and `$jobs` are being defined

Comment: Sorry I thought I had that in there. Edited the code now. I changed to 1000ms and still had issues

Comment: I really don't see any issue with your code, looks perfectly fine. What happens if you reduce the threads from 32 to 8 ?

Comment: actually the only issue I see is that `WaitAny` supports at most 64 tasks. check if you're not over that number

Comment: Not sure about WaitAny but this needs to run over a span of 5000+ systems. I agree 100ms was too little. I changed it to 5000 because 5 seconds is fine. The previous method would take way too long, potentially several minutes if not over a dozen or two minutes because each ping times out usually after 3 tries and if there are 300 users with systems down, this could add up. I changed the threads to 8 so don't know if that made a difference but it was still behaving strange until I changed to 5000ms.

Comment: so if you try to `WaitAny` with too many tasks you will get an error with: _Exception calling "WaitAny" with "1" argument(s): "The number of WaitHandles must be less than or equal to 64._. Basically, you need to check inside your first loop if `$jobs.Count` is equal to 64 and wait there too to release some tasks. A RunspacePool is also not great here because it will create 5k tasks beforehand. `CreateRunspace` is better here. This module can help you simplify your code: https://github.com/santisq/PSParallelPipeline/tree/main or if you have pwsh 7+ then `ForEach-Object -Parallel` is much better

Comment: Unfortunately, the systems are running on the default 5 but I'll take a look at that module and I see you are the author :)

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use your module with that entire block? I'm a bit new to runspaces and jobs.

Comment: sure, using that module the code would be like this: https://gist.github.com/santisq/a8c1bb8ae2d84a699772dcb37bfb29a6#file-example-invokeparallel-ps1 pretty simple

Comment: that is very simple. I'll install this module and give this a try. Thanks

Comment: `No C# source path found. Skipping BuildManaged...` . any idea how to get the build.ps1 to succeed?

Comment: Are you looking to update the source code? If not then you're going the wrong way. You just need to `Install-Module PSParallelPipeline -Scope CurrentUser` then that's it, the module is already available for you to use

Comment: Thanks, got that installed but running that throws an error so not sure if your example is correct for my scenario. `Invoke-Parallel : Exception calling "Wait" with "1" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred."
At line:4 char:5
+     Invoke-Parallel {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-Parallel], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AggregateException,Invoke-Parallel`

Comment: Out of curiosity, I set the seconds to 1 and it actually worked. If I set it to anything over 2, it fails. Is there a reason it is doing that? Also I basically need to get all the computers into an `@online` variable so that I can further process them, so how would I then add these to that if they are being done this way?

Comment: are you only interested in finding out the computers having that port opened? if so I can post an answer of how I would do it

Comment: I would like to see your code but actually I need to process these systems further by `invoke-command -Session $RemoteSession` a block which executes on all hosts. Thanks

Comment: hopefully that answer helps, otherwise im out of ideas :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've stated in comments, I don't really see something wrong with your code that could be causing output being duplicated or missing output. I do see though that 100ms to await the task is too little time, I would recommend at least 1 second.

Another point is that [`WaitHandle.WaitAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitany?view=net-8.0) supports top 63 wait handles in STA Mode (PowerShell default), from the **Remarks** section of the documentation:

> The maximum number of the wait handles is 64, and 63 if the current thread is in [STA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.apartmentstate?view=net-8.0#system-threading-apartmentstate-sta) state.

Ideally, you would need to consume the tasks if that number is reached in the first loop before continuing with the rest (this requires additional logic that checks if `$jobs.Count -eq 63`).

Lastly, I would recommend error handling in your code, this is to avoid aggregate exceptions caused by the [`.Wait` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-8.0#system-threading-tasks-task-wait).

Now, since you're already aware of and currently have installed the [`PSParallelPipeline` Module](https://github.com/santisq/PSParallelPipeline), this is how I would approach the code:

```bash
$maxThreads = 32
$timespan = [timespan]::FromSeconds(5)
 
$result = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Sales, DC=example,DC=com' | Invoke-Parallel {
    $outObject = [pscustomobject]@{
        Computer = $_.Name
        Port     = 5985
        PortOpen = $false # <= Assume Port Closed Here
    }

    try {
        $tcp = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]::new()
        # if the connection was successful, this property gets updated
        $outObject.PortOpen = $tcp.ConnectAsync($_.Name, 5985).Wait($using:timespan)
    }
    catch {
        # ignore any errors here, this avoids the exception:

        # System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060):
        # A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
        # or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
    }
    finally {
        # dispose the TCP instance
        if ($tcp) {
            $tcp.Dispose()
        }
    }

    # output the object
    $outObject
} -ThrottleLimit $maxThreads

# get all computers with the port open
$computersWithPortOpen = $result | Where-Object PortOpen | ForEach-Object Computer
# do other stuff with `$computersWithPortOpen`
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computersWithPortOpen .....
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work as intended. I'll test it further and return with marking it as solved.